# Attach prototype to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Let's say I have the following JSON with person objects.

```
[
  {
     "name": "Alice",
     "age": 28,
  },
  {
     "name": "Bob",
     "age": 33
  }
]
```

If I parse this, I will get an array with two JavaScript objects.
Let's say, I want to equip these two objects with a method called introduce, that does something like this

```
function introduce() {
  return "My name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old.";
}
```

Now, I could iterate over my two people and call

```
person.constructor.prototype.introduce = introduce
```

However, this will expose the introduce function in ALL JavaScript objects, not just the two above.

I could also manually attach the function to each object, but if I want to extend my people with additional functions, I will have to iterate over all people again.

Ideally, I would like a prototype that I can fit with the `introduce` method and then attach this prototype to all my people, so if I later extend the prototype, my people will gain additional functions as well.

The question is: how?

Comment: just do `person.prototype.introduce = introduce` and get rid of the `constructor` part.

Comment: why dont just make a `Person` class, parse json to make `Person`. Anytime add any function to `Person` prototype.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: I think `person` is his reference to the object itself, so `person.prototype` won't exist.

Comment: mshsayem, I think it's a bit verbose and it seems inefficient to throw thousands of newly deserialized objects away just to create identical copies with a different prototype. It perplexes me that you cannot specify a prototype when parsing an array of objects.

Comment: @NielsB. You could easily write a wrapper around `JSON.parse` for this specific purpose, using `Object.setPrototypeOf` (check my answer).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **deprecated** `__proto__` property or the ES6 method `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Note that it is **strongly discouraged** to mutate the prototype of an object (c.f. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) but it seems to be a legitimate usecase.

```
var you = { name: "Niels B." }
you.__proto__ = { hello: function () { console.log(this.name) } }
you.hello()
```

So for your specific problem:

```
function Person() {}
Person.prototype = {
  introduce: function () {
    return "My name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old.";
  }
}
```

Then for each person:

```
person.__proto__ = Person.prototype;
// or
Object.setPrototypeOf(person, Person.prototype);
```

Here's a relevant JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/parse-json-into-an-object-and-assign-a-prototype

Related thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ringojs/PxS1O5jMx-8

Comment: This adds the method to `Object.prototype`. The question states that he doesn't want to add the method to all objects.

Comment: @cookiemonster pretty sure it doesn't, it only mutates the prototype of the object.

Comment: @cookiemonster try it in a repl, the method is only added to this specific object.

Comment: I updated my comment with a demo. Any object created from object literal syntax will have `Object.prototype` as the first object in its prototype chain. The `__proto__` will reference the first object in the chain.

Comment: @cookiemonster mmh you're right, sorry. When I tried it in the chrome console it didn't seem to affect other objects. My bad.

Comment: That's strange, though I usually don't trust consoles for testing code. They do odd things sometimes.

Comment: @cookiemonster I edited the code, I think now it's right (although mutating the proto is still a bad idea except for a quick hack).

Comment: Yes, that'll avoid the extension that was happening, though I agree with out about not swapping proto objects.

Comment: Note, that IE9 & IE10 _cannot_ reassign the `__proto__` (IE11 is ok) and no IE supports `setPrototypeOf`. This answer won't work if IE < 11 support is necessary.

Comment: @rgthree thanks for pointing it out! (although people who use IE should die, imo).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to create a class:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lecezamo/1/edit)

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(person) {
        this.person = person;
        this.name = person.name;
        this.age = person.age;
    }
    Person.prototype.introduce = function () {
        return "My name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old.";
    };
    return Person;
})();
```

Comment: Hey! Might be a silly question but what's the reason for wrapping this in an IIFE?

Comment: @Aegis Private variables and methods!

Answer (score 3):

You're question is a little fuzzy to understand. But I think you don't want your "person" to be a regular object, but rather a separate person "class:"

```
var Person = function(obj){
    this.name = obj.name;
};

Person.prototype.introduce = function(){
  return console.log('hi, I\'m '+this.name);
};

var personA = new Person({ name:'a' });
var personB = new Person({ name:'b' });

personA.introduce();  // "hi, I'm a"
personB.introduce();  // "hi, I'm b"
```

Comment: So basically the conclusion is that it's not possible to gracefully assign prototypes to existing (literal) objects. Instead, new objects must be created using a constructor function.

Comment: @NielsB. Well, while it may be possible, you do not _want_ to do that, since you only want `introduce` available to _certain_ objects, in my example a `Person` instance.

Comment: Yes, I know. I don't want to replace the prototype for ALL objects, but it intuitively seems more efficient to iterate over an array and replace the prototype reference instead of creating a whole new set of objects.

Answer (score 3):

Make a simple `Person` class:

```
function Person(name,age){
    this.name = name; 
    this.age = age
}
```

Say, you have this array:

```
var people = [
  {
     "name": "Alice",
     "age": 28,
  },
  {
     "name": "Bob",
     "age": 33
  }
];
```

Convert `people` to `Person` array:

```
people = people.map(function(p){
    return new Person(p.name,p.age)
});
```

Add the method to prototype:

```
Person.prototype.introduce = introduce
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a person class and use Person.prototype :

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age= age;
}

function introduce() {
  return "My name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old.";
}

Person.prototype.introduce = introduce;

p1 = new Person ("bob", 33);
p1.introduce();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a structure for these people.

```
var Person = function Person(init){
 this.name = init.name;
 this.age = init.age;
};
Person.constructor = Person;
```

And then iterating to build the people.

```
var people = [];
for(var i = 0; i < yourJson.length; i++){
 people.push(new Person(yourJson[i]));
}
```

Now that the people are built, perhaps you would like to allow them to be able to introduce themselves. You can simply extend your Person "class" (definition).

```
Person.prototype.introduce = function() {
  return "My name is " + this.name + " and I am " + age + " years old.";
}
```

which will allow them to use this function

```
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
 console.log(people[i].introduce());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to re construct every time you could try this:

```
var people =[
  {
     "name": "Alice",
     "age": 28,
  },
  {
     "name": "Bob",
     "age": 33
  }
],
i=-1,len=people.length,tmp
,proto={
  sayName: function(){
    console.log("from sayname",this.data.name);
  }
};
while(++i<len){
  tmp=Object.create(proto);
  tmp.data=people[i];
  people[i]=tmp;
}
people[0].sayName();
proto.sayName=function(){console.log("changed it");};
people[1].sayName();
```

If your JSON objects have many members then this could save you from having to copy them in your constructor function but I'm not sure if you're getting more performance out of it.